# How to Optimize Firebase Data Read

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to understand how firebase data read is count.Is there any way to use hashmap so that whole data read is count as a single read. I have below code currently to fetch data from firebase where I am saving each child value in separate string variable to use in another purpose. Not understanding is it counting as a single read or multiple. is there any better way to do this?

```
reference.orderByKey().equalTo(bidPosition).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

          if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren() && !bidPosition.isEmpty()){

          String eta = datas.child("eta").getValue(String.class);
          String riderid = datas.child("uid").getValue(String.class);
          String drivierid = datas.child("did").getValue(String.class);
          String drivier_ratings = datas.child("dRat").getValue(String.class);
          String r_Fare = datas.child("tAmt").getValue(String.class);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database isn't billed in terms of number of reads.  You might be confusing it with Firestore, which *is* billed, in part, based on the number of documents read.

For Realtime Database, the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) makes it clear. You are charged for $5/GB stored (regardless of how it's read), and $1/GB downloaded.  How you download/read the data doesn't matter - it's the total volume that counts.  So there is really no way to significantly optimize a read or query operation that fetches some data.

Comment: is that same for delete also?

Comment: The pricing page doesn't say anything about being charged for data deletion. You might be charged some tiny amount of data download to receive the result of the deletion, but that doesn't seem at all significant.